# How to overfit GANs with a single image

Tags: generative-adversarial-networks, overfitting

When designing CNN for image recogition a commonly used sainty check to see if a model is working/designed fine is to see if we are able to overfit the model with a very small subset of images.

I am trying out GANs. While designing GAN I took a dataset with just one image(full black image). I used the DCGAN implementation in pytorch website[code link](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/dcgan_faces_tutorial.html).

I tried training the model with this just one black image and even after training for 100s-1000 epochs. I am not able to overfit the model ie generate a black (or something close). All what is generated are random noise image as below[image]

However the model does work well for celeba dataset(the one used in the tutorial). Which means the model is good. Can anybody help me why overfitting is very difficult/impossible when using a single image.

Comment: Complete guess here, but it might be the loss function. If the desired image is completely black perhaps all the 0 values are not giving any cost, and so the GAN never actually learns anything.

Comment: hi @Recessive , Thanks for the response this does make a point. To validate on this I took an image from MNIST dataset and I tired overfitting the model and tried training for 1000 iterations. I was still getting Random Noise. Then I had a thought that the number of epochs (1000) were a lot less as the original MNIST had 60000 images. I trained the model with mnist image for 10000 iterations and within almost 4000 iterations it started to overfit and started mimicing my input image.  Then I went ahead and tried with the black image and it was difficult for it to mimic the black colour

Comment: but however after about 10000+ epochs the noise was still present but I got an increase in pixels that were close to black.

Comment: Hi, I am working on the same problem now. Did you manage to figure out the problem? Thanks

Comment: Training more epochs was the solution